# Node JS copy only certain files

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, fs

I have an input directory like this:

```
resouces
├── a.avi
├── b.mp3
├── c.pdf
├── d.png
└── ...
```

I'm trying to generate the following one:

```
resouces
├── audio
    └── *.mp3
├── video
    └── *.avi
└── ...
```

I'm using fs-extra npm module. This is my code:

```
fse.ensureDir(resourcesOutputDirectory, (error) => {
    if (error) {
        console.err("An error ocurred creating the resources directory " + error.message);
    } else {
        fse.copy(resourcesInputDirectory, resourcesOutputDirectory, "/**/*.mp3", (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.err("An error ocurred moving resource directory to XML exported directory " + err.message);
            } else {
                console.log("Files has been succesfully copied");
            }
         });
     }
});
```

I don't know how to correctly use the filter option (third argument in copy call) to copy only certain files to my output directory.

Thank in advance!

Comment: Reading `fse` documentation lead me to believe, althought the exemple in the doc is obviously wrong, that instead of `"/**/*.mp3"`, you are supposed to put a function, that return `true` when you want to copy the file, and `false` when not. Like `(file) => {return (file.endsWith('.mp3');}`

Answer (score 2):

[Looking at the docs](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra#copy) it doesn't look as if you can use globs (as you are doing in your example). You can either use a function that returns a boolean, or a regular expression.

For instance, if you want to match all mp3s or avis then you can do;

```
fse.copy(inDir, outDir, /.*(.mp3|.avi)$/, (err) => { })
```

Comment: This was my first approach. But it didn't copy anything. Y try {filter: {test: /.*(.mp3|.avi)$/}}, as docs said: filter: Function or RegExp to filter copied files. If function, return true to include, false to exclude. If RegExp, same as function, where filter is filter.test. But it didn't work :(

Comment: This doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use this [gist](https://gist.github.com/akshayjai1/83c277a016786b70e66c7ff92deb7e82) to selectively copy files from a folder and provide specific output name

```js
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const folders = [
  {
    path: './build/static/css',
    regex: /^(main).[\w]*.css$/,
    outputFile: '../public-pages/style/sme.css'
  },
  {
    path: './build/static/js',
    regex: /^(main).[\w]*.js$/,
    outputFile: '../public-pages/js/sme.js'
  }
];
/*
following code will copy files from ./build/static/css matching the regex pattern to new location specified by output file
*/
folders.forEach(folder => {
  fs.readdirSync(folder.path).forEach(file => {
    if (folder.regex.test(file)) {
      console.log(`copying file ${file}`);
      fs.copy(`${folder.path}/${file}`, folder.outputFile)
        .then(() => console.log('success!'))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it:

As @Jivings said, I just need a regular expression as filter. But, the problem is that copy method from fse uses ncp, and it seems to have a bug with filter right now. Using copySync works.